# How to parent a bone to an empty?

Tags: rigging, bones, parent

I've got a Problem, because I'm trying to create this ([Rigging an umbrella-like object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86804/rigging-an-umbrella-like-object)) -but I just can't figur out how to parent the bone to the empty.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Selecting the bone and then the empty -> Crtl+P works for me. Do you run into problems?

Comment: Do you select the bone in Pose Mode? -And is it a single bone or is it connected to others?

Comment: @Dimali : this seems to parent the armature, not the bone

Answer (score 5):

In pose mode, set a *Child of* bone constraint on your bone, and use your object as target.