# Objects rotating weirdly

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to animate the movement of the wooden sculpture that I made. I'm stuck trying to rotate each stick of this model vertically up and down so it would touch the stick of the lower part of the model at approximately 45 degrees, but it won't work.
I tried setting the origin to everything i found in the Set Origin menu, but it still behaves weirdly and also I tried to rotate it around the short edge and selecting Active Element and Normal in Edit mode but still I got the same kind of rotation.
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure you did not apply the rotation to your arms objects (which you seem to already have), otherwise it will be harder to achieve this. Also make sure the pivot of each object is at the desired rotation center to make it easier. This may help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86804/rigging-an-umbrella-like-object/

Comment: Thanks! I actually started again from the beginning and I think it's going better now. I did all the rotations while the cube was still in its original position and then just duplicated the arms and positioned them along the middle part.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the problem, but I think what is wrong is that your pivot point is off. Tab edit mode, select the face you want to be a hinge, snap cursor to selected, then set the rotation point to cursor. Let's hope it works!

Comment: I was impatient and figured my way around it without solving this problem, but thanks!

Comment: Anytime you need it!