# How to setup reciprocating compressor rig?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, physics

Note: I put my object names in "".

I need to rig this reciprocating compressor such, that rotating the "Rotary Base" at its center, should pull the "Rotary Shaft" at the "Pivot" (which is a child of "Rotary Base"). I achieved this by applying a Copy Location object constraint on the Rotary Shaft and setting the target to "Pivot".

[image]

Now I need to lock the movement of the "Piston Shaft" on the X-axis, as it should go in and out of the "Cylinder". How can I somehow link the right-end of the "Rotary Shaft" to the left-end of the "Piston Shaft" while maintaining the "Rotary Shaft" movement with the "Rotary Base"(basically, the right-end of the "Rotary Shaft" should be locked on the X-axis while the left should be able to move.)?

I am open to other workflows (armatures included), so please.

The file I included, only has the models. The constraints and stuff I removed.

[image]

Comment: Does [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n27rgkp5UmQ) help?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86804/rigging-an-umbrella-like-object